# How do I create a dockable "perspective-like" view in Eclipse PDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I've been searching for this information via Google but can't seem to get a satisfactory answer.

I wish to create a dockable view (similar to the "[perspective](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-21.htm)" selection toolbar item) in Eclipse but don't really know which is the appropriate extension point to use.

The intent of this is to create some buttons on the top left of the toolbar when a certain perspective is activated. The "perspective" type view matches the behavior I wish to see.

So my question is:

- Is this type of view reserved *only* for switching perspectives?
- If so, what extension point should I look at, if not which extension point should I look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a toolbar with your own commands to the main toolbar using `org.eclipse.ui.menus`.  You would put a `visibleWhen` element on the command elements if you want it only visible when a certain perspective is open.

```
<visibleWhen>
   <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
      <equals value="the.perspective.id"/>
   </with>
</visibleWhen>
```

See [Toolbar Example](https://github.com/paulweb515/eclipseExamples/blob/master/org.eclipse.example.commands.toolbar/plugin.xml#L38) for an example of the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point, and [Plugging into the Workbench](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd.htm) for some basics on commands.